# C# help for serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a big problem with serialization.
 I don't know what the problem is but i can show all element on my class.

i made graph with node.
But the only problem.

I used interface for implement a type of element for connection.
example bool can connect with bool and etc.

I have

```
   [Serializable]
        public class Node : IElement
        {
          //More Constructor..
          public IEnumerable<NodeConnection>    Connections { get { return connections; } }

        public IEnumerable<NodeItem>        Items       { get { return nodeItems; } }

        public ElementType ElementType { get { return ElementType.Node; } }


        }
```

ElementType is an Interface

with Node : IElement

```
public interface IElement
    {
        ElementType ElementType { get; }
    }
```

at serialization I have this error

```
 BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(sv.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

bin.Serialize(fs,graph.graphNode); //Error here
```

*Type 'Example' in Assembly 'Graph, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.*

the graph.graphNode in Serialization method are a simple List
anyone have a idea?

Comment: The errors mentions type "Example", please show it to us, and/or make sure it has the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: It says Example type is not market as serializable. Do you have example class? Can you show content of that class? Is it market serializable?

Comment: yes it's marked serializable. look my example serialization code
`bin.Serialize(fs,graph.graphNode);` the list are this  `public List<Node> graphNodes = new List<Node>();` and the class are marked serializzable look top  Node : IElement

Comment: The code provided makes no mention of this `Example` class.  We can't help without it.

Comment: @Amy the "Example" is the FormApplication, graph are the UserControl.
and graph.graphNode are the List.
From Application "Example" i just write a BinaryFormatter and serialize all element in the UserControl. Then i have this error

Comment: Seeing as we don't have the code for FormApplication *either*, that comment was not helpful.

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot help as is, without the Example, FormApplication classes and whatever else you're trying to serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is called class Example {} then you probably have one or more event handlers tied up to your Nodes or NodeItems. If Node and/or NodeItem implements INotifyPropertyChanged for example and the form (Example class) binds to PropertyChanged then bin.Serialize() tries to serialize the whole form.

Solution: Use

```
[field: NonSerialized]
```

on all your events in the classes you want to serialize, if they are consumed by classes that are not mend to be serialized:

For example:

```
[field: NonSerialized]
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

To be more precise:

```
  public class Example : Form
  {
    Node _node;

    public Example()
    {
      _node = new Node();
      _node.MyEvent += _node_MyEvent; // This will cause the BinaryFormatter to try to serialize Example form when serializing _node - unless [field: NonSerialized] attribute is used.
    }

    private void _node_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class Node
  {
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
  }
```

**EDIT**

The same is true if a serializable class reference a non serializeable object:

```
[Serializable]
class Connection
{
   // Use [NonSerialized] attribute to prevent serialization of this reference:
   [NonSerialized]
   public Example; // A reference to a non serialized object
}
```

Comment: Tanks Henrik, one problem is done, now i cannot serializze Connection. Look this screenshoot (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/207183378447990784/241150291414614016/unknown.png) this is my graph control. if i dont connect the Node, and serialize it, work, else if i connect all nodes, i have same error but small change,  

ype 'GraphNodes.ExampleForm' in Assembly 'GraphNodes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: @JoeMartiniello: I didn't get it by viewing your screendump. But my guess is that you may have a reference in Connection to ExampleForm. See my edit above.